# Notification light on Galaxy S3 SGH-T999V with Cyanogenmod 10

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, notification-led

I'm trying to get custom notification lights working on applications I define on my GS3.
I went to Settings > System > Notification Light and added an app with the colour I want.  The light doesn't seem to turn on when I have a notification.  I tried the Test and locked my screen but that doesn't work either.
It seems like the light only seems to turn on when the phone is plugged in.